# Why should $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x}^T$ be a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  I've seen some authors say that  $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T$ is a matrix.  I suppose if I was to blindly follow the rules of matrix multiplication, this would make sense.

Is there a formal definition for this sort of procedure, or is this just convenient shorthand?

Comment: By $\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^n$, the author means that $\mathbf x$ is a column vector.  Certainly a column vector times a row vector will result in a matrix.  In fact, $\mathbf x\mathbf y^T$ is something called the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) (to distinguish it from the *inner product* $\mathbf x^T\mathbf y$).

Comment: @Bye_World I've not run into this in my experience with linear algebra.  cdwe has pointed out that this is called an outer product.

Comment: Well, now you have. ;-)

Comment: But you have run into it. You know that an $i \times j$ matrix multiplied by a $j \times k$ matrix is an $i \times k$ matrix. Since an $n$-dimensional column vector is the same thing as an $n \times 1$ matrix, and since an $n$-dimensional row vector is the same thing as a $1 \times n$ matrix, it follows that a column vector times a row vector is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @LeeMosher Hmm, that is a fairly convincing argument.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called [outer product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec{x}$ is a row vector, then $\vec{x}\,\vec{x}^t$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix: Let $\vec{x}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. Hence
$$
\vec{x}\,\vec{x}^t=
(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}=(a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2)
$$
Note that if $\vec{x}$ denote a column vector, say
$$
\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
then $\vec{x}\,\vec{x}^t$ is a $n\times n$ matrix: 
$$
\vec{x}\,\vec{x}^t=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}
(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1a_1 & a_1a_2 & \cdots & a_1a_n \\
a_2a_1 & a_2a_2 & \cdots & a_2a_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
a_na_1 & a_na_2 & \cdots & a_na_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$